# jni.h: No such file or directory

Tags: java, java-native-interface, native

I need to compile this library file using gcc compiler but getting error.
Although all tools are available.  `jni.h` is on the way `D:\JDK 8\include`

```
D:\JNIProject\src\main\java>gcc -I${JAVA_HOME}/include -I${JAVA_HOME}/include/win32 -o libmylib.jnilib -shared NativeClass.cpp
In file included from NativeClass.cpp:1:
NativeClass.h:2:10: fatal error: jni.h: No such file or directory
    2 | #include <jni.h>
      |          ^~~~~~~
```

NativeClass.cpp

```
#include "NativeClass.h"
#include <stream>
#include <math>
#include <string>
#include <jni.h>
using namespace std;

JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_NativeClass_addOtherMethod
  (JNIEnv *, jclass, jstring st1, jstring st2) {
   // some code
}
```

NativeClass.h

```
/* DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE - it is machine generated */
#include <jni.h>
/* Header for class NativeClass */

#ifndef _Included_NativeClass
#define _Included_NativeClass
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif
/*
 * Class:     NativeClass
 * Method:    addOtherMethod
 * Signature: (Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;)V
 */
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_NativeClass_addOtherMethod
  (JNIEnv *, jclass, jstring, jstring);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
#endif
```

NativeClass.java

```
public class NativeClass {
    static {
        System.loadLibrary("lib");
    }
    public static native void addOtherMethod(String first, String second);
}
```

JAVA_HOME=D:\JDK 8

I tried not to specify JAVA_HOME, but to register manually. Did not help
I tried:

`gcc /I "$(JAVA_HOME)\include" /I "$(JAVA_HOME)\include\win32" -o libmylib.jnilib -shared NativeClass.cpp`

and also

`gcc /I "D:\JDK 8\include" /I "D:\JDK 8\include\win32" -o libmylib.jnilib -shared NativeClass.cpp`

Comment: The path to your JDK has a space in it (in `JDK 8`). Does it help if you surround command-line arguments that contain with double quotes? Also, the Windows convention for environment-variable lookups is `%VAR_NAME%`, not `${VAR_NAME}`. What happens if you try replacing `-I${JAVA_HOME}/include` with `"-I%JAVA_HOME%/include"` (and similarly for the other argument)?

Comment: @LukeWoodward I tried, if my hands are not crooked, then no, nothing has changed

Comment: How about if you reinstall Java in a directory that doesn't have spaces in it pathname?

Comment: @StephenC FWIW, I've had problems similar to this when using gcc under MSYS2 - paths with spaces are handled poorly.  It's bad enough our group's Windows installer for our product has a big "DO NOT INSTALL THIS INTO A LOCATION WITH SPACES IN ANY PATH COMPONENT" warning.